# Is it less secure to have DB config variables on page when using PDO?

Tags: pdo

Is it OK to have my database call on the actual page when using PDO or is it more secure to include it as a config file? I only have 4 pages with sql queries, so I'm not concerned about putting it on each page from a time saving standpoint. Just want to make sure it is not less secure to do so like this:

```
$user='***'; // Enter your DB User Name.
$pass='***!'; // Enter your DB Password.
$hostName='***'; // Enter your host name.
$dataBaseName='***'; // Enter your Database Name.
$dbh = new pdo('mysql:host='.$hostName.';dbname='.$dataBaseName, $user, $pass);
echo "Connection Successful";

//Begin PDO Queries...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving The database credential in a config file is not going to improve any security.

It is more about code reusability. It is just good practice to avoid repetition.